# Creating custom field on Customer Record Form Showing Total Transaction from Year to date

Tags: netsuite

I need to display customer total transaction form current fiscal year to date on customer record form in NetSuite. This will be a dynamic custom field. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to set the custom field to the total via a Scheduled Script or a Workflow that runs every day.
The Script would need to:

1. Search for all customers that need the Total Transaction field set.
2. Iterate over those customers => Calculate the total, and then set the total field on each customer record.